# What setting causes case sensitive require_once paths?

Tags: php

On my local environment I require_once `publiccontroller.php` and it'll load `publicController.php`

Unfortunately when I go to production on HostGator it will fail because it's not loosely requiring/including files.  Is this a PHP or Apache thing?  I need my environments to be mirrored so I'd like to change my local setting to match my production server.

Comment: It is usually an OS thing.  If you are developing on Windows, paths may not be case sensitive.  On just about every other system, they _are_ case sensitive. Always code with filesystem case sensitivity in place. It is a misfeature of Windows.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Filesystem case-sensitivity is not a PHP setting, but rather specific to the OS and filesystem.  Windows filesystems tend to be case-insensitive, while most other operating systems prefer case-sensitive filesystems.

Since you cannot necessarily predict what OS your code will run on in the future, it is recommended to *always* code for case-sensitive fileystems.

If you are currently developing on Windows (or any other OS with case-insensitive filesystems), the best course of action is to return to your code and fix all the file paths to use the correct casing, matching what they are named on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Case-sensitivity is an issue that operating systems are responsible for. Many developers who develop php on `Windows` usually face this problem. Because Windows is not case-sensitive and a developer usually doesn't have any problem with addresses and file name during development process, but when they move their web application to a Linux server the hidden problem appears because addresses and filenames are different in Linux and there is a different between for instance `Myfile.php` and `myfile.php`.

So, just as a recommendation, try to develop your web apps on Linux. It gives you a better and more stable environment for PHP programming.

Comment: A better recommendation would have been to pay attention on case sensitivity instead of to start developing in Linux environment.

Comment: yeah..it is a true idea too...but it would be better to develop programs on linux...because the final server of web application are usually Linux sever...it's just a recommendation...