# PHP Autoload ignorecase

Tags: php

Is there any way to call require_once with some "case insensitive flag" ? 
In windows it's okay, but linux is case sensitive. Is there any way to override ?
Thanks

Comment: You can refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431782/what-setting-causes-case-sensitive-require-once-paths

Comment: Thats not really related to autoloading. An autoloader is a callback registered with `spl_register_autoloader()`, within you can do whatever you like to map a classname to a filename. However, you should start to take case-sensitivity serious and not this loosely windows-style case-insensitive behaviour ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, load

```
strtolower($className . ".php")
```

and name your files in lowercase.

---

Regardless of how you try to load your files, only the lowercase version will ever be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this every time you are loading you auto load the appropriate classes. yu have to change the directories depends on you project. you can you the echo or print_r to print what classes are loaded every time when you are calling something. also all you class names must ot have the same format for example, className.class.php e.g Dashboard.class.php, Category.class.php. you can use 
ucwords to make the first letter capital.

```
function __autoload($className) 
{
    if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../library/' . strtolower($className) . '.class.php')) 
    {
        require_once(__DIR__ . '/../library/' . strtolower($className) . '.class.php');
    }
    else if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../application/controllers/' . strtolower($className) . '.php')) 
    {
        require_once(__DIR__ . '/../application/controllers/' . strtolower($className) . '.php');
    }
    else if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../application/models/' . strtolower($className) . '.php')) 
    {
        require_once(__DIR__ . '/../application/models/' . strtolower($className) . '.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include some where else in you header.php or some other common file.,

```
<?php
$filename = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$request = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

if($filename != $request)
  die('Case of filename and request do not match!');
?>
```

I think this may help you resolve your problem. also refer the following location https://superuser.com/questions/431342/linux-both-case-sensitive-and-case-insensitive-and-always-inconvenient