# Is there a way to include files case insensitively in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, apache, filesystems, case-insensitive

I'm into a legacy PHP project which is developed in WAMP windows platform.

Code-base is heavy and it has lot of files included via include, require language constructs. File naming convention is not consistent, having small cases, camel cases as file names.
As Linux does not support case insensitive file includes, I'm not sure how to run this in my apache. Since include, require are PHP language constructs, could not override them as well. Is there any way to make this run?

I'm actually using Ubuntu for my development. 
P.S: Some suggested that the only way is to make the file names consistent. But the problem is having many hundreds of files and existing team is not comfortable in coming out of windows.

Wondering if this could be achieved. Any help and insights will be much helpful.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431782/what-setting-causes-case-sensitive-require-once-paths) is an old answer, but just reinforces what you already know.

Comment: If you don’t want to modify PHP itself at the source level (to implement an actual “search” for matching file names there), then I don’t see much of an option besides having this handled on the file system level itself already. With the EXT4 file system, that seems to be possible - https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=EXT4-Case-Insensitive-Linux-5.2 The other alternative would be that you develop under Windows as well then, maybe using a VM / docker or something.

Comment: Maybe you could mount a FAT32 filesystem to store the files on?

Comment: @MarkSetchell That works! I already had a FAT32 partition where I could host and along with some Apache configuration changes, I was able to run the app. Thanks!
Can you please post it as an answer as this might help someone in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could use (and it seems you have already) a FAT32 filesystem mounted up somewhere suitable to act as a case-insensitive filesystem for your PHP files.